# Google Search and Own Website Search?

Tags: search, google-search

I am using [Google Custom Search Plugin](http://littlehandytips.com/plugins/google-custom-search/) . But when I am searching any thing by selecting **google** it shows the results that matches to any keyword on my server websites but I want it too search the results which I go and search on [google](http://www.google.com) .

If it is not possible with this plugin then is there any other plugin same like this which has two options of searching. Either from google or from my website (e.g www.abc.com)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a form that submits direct to Google? This would be the simplest solution (assuming you want to search every website in the world):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Google"/>
<input type="submit" /></form>
```

I believe that would do the job you want it to. The result would look something like:

https://www.google.com/search?q=this%20that